# Using radioButtons to Display Columns in Datatable (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to display columns in a datatable using radioButtons that the user can change.

So far my code is:

**UI:**

```
fluidRow(column(4, radioButtons("radio","Choose:",c("A","B"))))),
fluidRow(DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
```

**Server:**

**output**

```
$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
  DT::datatable({table

  if (input$radio != "A") {
    table <- table[,1:5]
  }

  if (input$radio != "B") {
    table <- table[,6:10)]
  }

  table

})},rownames = FALSE,options = list(lengthMenu = c(25,50,100)))
```

When I run the app all it shows is the radioButtons with A and B but no datatable.

Comment: why not just use the colVis extension? https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html

Comment: in line 2 of your `output$table`, `DT::datatable({table` what is "table" there for?

Comment: @Addison Hayes Can you accept the answer if it was helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of issues with your code. I fixed your code and tested on mtcars dataset.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
        radioButtons("radio","Choose:", choices = list("A" =  "A", "B" = "B"))
     ),

     mainPanel(
       dataTableOutput("table")
     )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    if (input$radio == "A") {
       table1 <- mtcars[,1:5]
    }
    else {
       table1 <- mtcars[,6:10]
    }
    table1
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you run this app, you will see it shows data table based on your radio button selection.